# Finding the minimum of $\frac pq + \frac rs$ for distinct integers $p, q, r, s$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots,16,17\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, fractions

Here is the question:

> Four distinct integers $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ are chosen from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, 16, 17\}$. The minimum possible value of $\frac pq + \frac rs$ can be written as $\frac ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive, co-prime integers. What is the value of $a+b$?

I got the answer as $321$. I took the numbers as $\frac pq$ as $\frac 1{16}$ and $\frac rs$ as $\frac 2{17}$ and added them to get $\frac ab = \frac{49}{272}$. Well I first took $\frac pq$ and $\frac rs$ as $\frac 1{17}$ and $\frac 2{16}$ respectively.

So without calculating both the results I wouldn't have got the answer. So can you help me by giving the way to get the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, we want the minimum, so as small $p,r$ as possible, and as large $q,s$ as possible. There are 2 choices:

$1/17+2/16=50/(16\cdot17)$ and $1/16+2/17=49/(16\cdot17)$. The second one is smaller, the fraction is $a/b=49/272$ and hence $a+b=321$.

I don't know what other answer you want. In general case of choosing from $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ you will get $a+b=(n+2(n-1))+(n(n-1))=n^2+2n-2$, the reasoning is the same.

Comment: So without calculating both we can't say which one is smaller?

Comment: Somehow we can: which is smaller: $2n+(n-1)$ or $n+2(n-1)$? But basically, maybe some complicated constructions would work such that you don't calculate the numbers. However, mathematics is not about making things complicated, only some people think it is.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{16} + \frac{2}{17} = \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{17} + \frac{1}{17}$

$\frac{2}{16} + \frac{1}{17} = \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{17}$

So obviously the first one is smaller.

Answer (score -1):

**p/q + r/s = (p.s + r.q)/q.s**

to gain smallest value, denominator **q.s** must be ***bigest***, there are **16** and **17** for **q** and **s**
and nominator must be ***smallest***, **p.17 + r.16**, so **p=1** and **r=2**

**(1.17 + 2.16) / 16.17 = 49/272 a+b=321**